# How to display the webform on the Home page?d

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Currently I'm using the md construction 7.x-1.6 theme and I want a form on the right hand side in the limit space of this theme.  What I need here is "WebForm" on the right side.

How can I proceed for this? How can I put anything anywhere in my drupal site? Which type of module is required for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to structure > blocks > and you can configure your blocks in the regions you like. I haven't used the theme you mentioned, but I think it must have the region right side-bar.

Comment: Can you plz suggest me how to make a numeric textField in WebForm for Mobile No. field ( it must accept the numeric only).

Comment: go for http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.module/group/field/7

Answer (score 0):

ok you can download a module called view and then create a view as place as your need.